# How to create a plugin in Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I tried to create a plugin but it failed
https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-create-an-import-content-plugin-part-1-4

Thanks!

Comment: We need more detail. Please check out this guide and add some details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Strapi comes with a full featured Command Line Interface (CLI) which lets you scaffold and manage your project in seconds.

step-1 : install strapi globally using the command

```
npm install -g strapi@beta
```

step-2 : generate the plugin using already installed the strapi-cli

```
strapi generate:plugin <name>
```

the above will generates an empty plugin called  in the ./plugins folder.

Example: `strapi generate:plugin user` will create the plugin at ./plugins/user.

to know more https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/cli/CLI.html#strapi-generate-plugin